# Trying to find the smallest/biggest number without a set value for variables

Tags: c#

I am new to coding and just started coding school.
Below you see a program asking you to type in 7 numbers, if you type in a word/letter it will return you to the beginning and not count, telling you to use numbers only.

Currently I am trying to figure out how to make sure the biggest smallest number doesnt give out 0 in case it's not typed in by the user.

Is there any way to make this happen with this bool method?
Effectively finding a way to not have smallest/biggest have value = 0.

```cs
using System;

namespace @bool
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i = 6, smallest = 0, biggest = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the 1. number");
            bool isNumber;

            while (i > 0)
            {
                string n = Console.ReadLine();
                isNumber = int.TryParse(n, out int number);
                if (isNumber)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Please enter the  {8 - i}. number");
                    if (number < smallest)
                    {
                        smallest = number;
                    }
                    if (number > biggest)
                    {
                        biggest = number;
                    }
                    i--;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number");
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"The biggest number is {biggest}");
            Console.WriteLine($"The smallest number is {smallest}");
        }
    }
}
```

Very glad it worked out with the bool method.

Currently I am trying to figure out how to make sure the biggest smallest number doesnt give out 0 in case it's not typed in by the user.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to set the initial value of '`smallest` to something that is bigger than what the user will enter.  Hint: there is a maximum value for signed 32-bit integers....

Comment: You shouldn't be trying to write code without knowing what it has to do first. Put down you keyboard and pick up a pen and paper. How would you solve this problem if it were wholly manual? That's how you determine the logic required. Once you have working logic, then you can write code to implement that logic specifically. If you don't have any logic, you shouldn't be thinking about code.

Comment: In your condition, `if (isNumber) { }`, you could add an additional condition to ensure it's greater than zero, e.g. `if (isNumber && number > 0) { }`. This along with @DavidJones comment should get you close.

Comment: Follow up question:
shouldn't the max value of an integer 32 be 2^32?
it seems to only accept 2^30

Comment: @Imbaland It's actually 2^31. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.maxvalue?view=net-7.0.

Comment: so its actually 2^31 - 1.
thanks a lot!

Comment: Or better yet, `int.MaxValue` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.maxvalue?view=net-7.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two approaches to this problem:

1. Use the smallest and biggest number at the start:

   ```
   int i = 6, smallest = Int32.MinValue, biggest = Int32.MaxValue;
   ```

   With this approach:

   1. You probably want to check if `biggest` is still `Int32.MaxValue`  printing its value at the end.
   2. If a user enters `2147483647` (`Int32.MaxValue`) or `-2147483648` (`Int32.MinValue`) the program will not work properly because it will not treat these values as a valid input.
   3. If you change the data type from `int` to another type (e.g. `long`) and forget to change the assignments (to `long.Min/MaxValue`) the program may not work properly in some cases (but the compiler will help with a warning if you change int to a smaller type e.g. `short`, or `sbyte`).
2. Use nullable values

   ```
   int i = 6;
   int? smallest = null, biggest = null;
   ```

   This way the program will require a bit more code (a few `.HasValue` checks) but `smallest` and `biggest` are always what they really are - no pretending - they're either not set or the smallest/biggest value.
   If biggest is `int?` (a nullable int) then

   ```
   if (number > biggest)
   {
       biggest = number;
   }
   ```

   becomes

   ```
   if(!number.HasValue || number > biggest)
   {
       biggest = number; 
   }
   ```

Comment: can u elaborate further on the null method?
so far i have found out that `.HasValue` is a bool type and returns true or false,
but i dont know how to assign the value to it afterwards and have trouble finding it.
tried to pass my code into here, but its too long unfortunately...

Comment: I added a snippet for the if for `int?`.

Comment: thanks a lot :-)
i actually made it work with a trypparse check and a bool, but your solution is much cleaner